# Contextmenu right click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

> http://jsbin.com/iGaHAtu/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Look at this link i want to get clicked table doom element . How can i do it ? 
I am going to try this code but doesn't worked.

For Example i want to column text when i clicked right and openned contextmenu.. Can anyone alert the inner column ?

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
    $contextMenu.css({
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    console.log($(this));
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Try $(e.target) for jquery object. Otherwise just e.target for the plain old javascript dom element.

Comment: it does not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(e.target)` for jquery object representing clicked element. Otherwise just use `e.target` for plain old javascript dom element.

In your case, to alert the column text, try this code:

```
$(function() {

  var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");

  $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
    $contextMenu.css({
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    alert($(e.target).text());
    return false;
  });

  $contextMenu.on("click", "a", function() {
     $contextMenu.hide();
  });

});
```

More on event.target here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: I want to element of TR this is give me just text :( I need element for read to body from parent or child...

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz You can use [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get parent. Use it like this: `$(e.target).parent('tr')`

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz If you want the html, you can do `alert($(e.target).parent('tr').html())`

Comment: Okay i got it :)Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First use TR>TD selector

`$("table tr >td").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
   alert($(this).text());
  //rest of the statements goes here
});`

Comment: I want to element of TR this is give me just text :( I need element for read to body from parent or child...

Comment: Do you mean all TDs of an TR, where you right click?

Comment: When i clicked right , I wan to TR doom element . Witch one i clicked

Comment: Please dont mind, I never heard a word doom in my programming career, unable to get you on this. It's better if you try using some other word for your required action!

Comment: I feel I got you, do you mean zoom there! And you need to create variable `$contextmenu` to work along with it to zoom! Correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer introduced [element.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), other browsers use [element.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tr", function(e) {
        var target = e.target.parentElement;
        var text = target.innerText || target.textContent;
        alert(text);
        return false;
    });
});
```